# Laravel 4 CSS file validation failing

Tags: php, laravel, mime-types, laravel-4

I have an upload form that has validation checks whether an item is a valid CSS file or not. I do try to upload a .css file but the validation fails.

Here's the bit where I try to validate the code on my controller:

```
private function _queueArticle($ref = NULL)
{

    $input = Input::all();
    $vrules = Config::get('validation.queue_article');

    //validate inputs
    $validation = Validator::make($input, $vrules);
    if ( $validation->fails() ) {
        return ( $ref === NULL ) ? 
            Redirect::to($redir_path)->withErrors($validation)->withInput() :
            Redirect::to($redir_path)->withErrors($validation);
    }

}
```

Here's what's `$vrules`:

```
'queue_article' => array(
    'title' => 'required|max:255',
    'body' => 'required',
    'slug' => 'unique:articles,slug',
    'hero' => 'required|image',
    'custom_css' => 'mimes:css'
)
```

I believe it's failing because it's using PHP's `finfo`, which is known to fail detecting css not as `text/css`, but rather `text/plain`. Doesn't Symfony, Laravel's 'companion code' here (don't know the term), has its own validation class that successfully clears CSS for what it is?

More importantly, what can I do about this?

**UPDATE**: Error message shows my custom error 'Please upload a valid CSS file.' From  app/lang/en/validation.php:

```
'custom' => array(
    'password_old' => array( 'required' => 'Please enter your current password.' ),
    'password' => array( 'confirmed' => 'The new passwords don\'t match.' ),
    'hero' => array(
        'required' => 'A header image is required.',
        'image' => 'The header file you included is not valid. Please upload a valid image.'
    ),
    'custom_css' => array('mimes' => 'Please upload a valid CSS file.')
)
```

**UPDATE 2**: I checked `var_dump($validation)` and showed zero contents on array `messages` and `failedRules`. It also shows the CSS file having mime type as `text/css`. All is well, eh, except when I `var_dump($validation->fails())` it returns a bool of `true`.

Additional info will be provided upon request.

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you think validation fails -> what is the error message?

Comment: @Andreyco More details have been added :)